# How to create an animation in xcode like the zite start up screen on iPad

Tags: xcode

I would like to create an app where the startup screen plays a simple animation.

For example, in the Zite app for iPad, the tiles are all bunched up at the start and then once loaded they all scatter in a set place where the news articles are.

How can animations be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention an iPad app as an example I guess you want your animation to play on iOS, and for that, Apple wrote a great [Core Animation Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514)

Comment: Thank you very much, i managed to find a solution for this but i also found some other things i was looking for in that guide :)